# TinyMCE - How can I have 2 editors on the same page with different plugins loaded?

Tags: tinymce

I have a page that has multiple TinyMCE editors on it. i would like one of them to have the autoresize plugin loaded and the other one i would like to stay a fixed size.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can, by simply instantiating the editors with different configurations.

For example, say you have two textareas (area1, area2). Instead of using

```
tinymce.init({
mode : "textareas",
...
});
```

which will load tinyMCE in for both textareas on the page, you can instead use

```
tinymce.init({
mode : "exact",
elements :"area1",
....
});

tinymce.init({
mode : "exact",
elements :"area2",
....
});
```

with different plugins in each config.

Comment: Can I initialize 2 editors with different mode attribute, one for all textareas, second with "exact" mode further use?

Answer (score 0):

The exact mode is usefull but don't workout in this case and others.

I'm trying to show 2 editors one in Portuguese and other in spanish (I tried fist in Engish but i'm not sure of the language code) and the interface shows only with the last language (last tinymce.init)

```js
tinymce.init({
mode : "exact",
elements : "area1",
language : 'es',
add_unload_trigger : false,
plugins : 'wordcount',
maxCharacters : 130 // this is a default value which can get modified later,
});

tinymce.init({
mode : "exact",
elements : "area2",
language : 'pt_PT',
add_unload_trigger : false,
plugins : "wordcount table",
maxCharacters : 50 // this is a default value which can get modified later,
});
```

I'll try some possible solutions and edit my answer today.